# ASP.NET Razor - Adding min attribute to Editor For using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor

I am trying to add the min value to a date field, so that the user cannot select a date that is in the previous month, so the value for min should be the 1st of this month.

The problem is I cannot find the id, through which I can refer the date field in my jQuery code.

This is the razor code for the startDate field.

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { min = "2019-07-01", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
 </div>
```

And this is my Javascript code.

```
<script type = "text/javascript>
function StartDateValidation() {
                var mm = GetMonth();
                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                return yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + 01;
            }

            function EndDateValidation() {
                var mm = GetMonth();
                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                var dd = GetLastDate();

                return yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#StartDate').setAttribute('min', StartDateValidation());
                $('#EndDate').setAttribute('min', EndDateValidation());
            }
}
</script>
```

The functions work fine, and are giving the desired output, some of which I haven't shown, to keep it clean.

But, it doesn't work, and the startDate field is still accepting previous month values.

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to share the Html code after the razor code is rendered? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I tried to find a converter, but it is not available. The razor get rendered internally.

Comment: I think timing issue, you are trying to set attribute before the form is rendered.

Comment: but, the javascript code will get executed only after the document is ready, right, as per the code $(document).ready();

Comment: Yes you are right, and i am not sure at what point of time you are loading the form (it is  a dynamic form ). for example you load a html page and the form is loaded later the timing issue occurs. So in general all Events or actions  are defined only after the corresponding Elements are rendered. I hope I am clear enough  else let me know. Thanks

Comment: PS: try to console.log your form in $(document).ready(); and see it it is available after the document is loaded

Comment: No, it's not the timing issue. The form is loaded as soon as the page loads. Can you tell me how to add an attribute inside the Htmlattributes of the form? Thanks

Comment: $('selector').attr("name", "value")

Comment: already tried that, not working

Comment: In between i see that document.ready function is included in a function. instead you have to use it after the script tag . example: <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){ // code here}) </script>

Comment: no, that's just indentation, see the '{' ends after function itself

Comment: oops my bad :-(. can i see the page online ? and also any chance of duplicate ID's

Comment: actually, I am running it in my localhost, so that might be a problem. I don't think, there is any problem of duplicate IDs. It's just that the attribute is not getting added to the field.